# turicreate visualizations (Google Collab environment) - SFrame.explore response "Materializing SFrame"

Tags: google-colaboratory

In a very simple workbook load data into an Sframe named "Students".

When I execute "Students" I get the expected results (just cut and pasted not actual results)

```
First Name  Last Name   Country         age
Bob         Smith       United States   24
Alice       Williams    Canada          23
Malcolm     Jone        England         22
Felix       Brown       USA             23
Alex        Cooper      Poland          23
Tod         Campbell    United States   22
Derek       Ward        Switzerland     25
```

[7 rows x 4 columns]

But when I enter "Students.explore()" I get the results

"Materializing SFrame"

I expected a GUI with a rich display describing the data. This is what I get when I use graphlab.create in a non - Google Collaboratory workbook.

Below is the code description and link to the turicreate API help.

"SFrame.explore([title])    Explore the SFrame in an interactive" GUI.https://apple.github.io/turicreate/docs/api/turicreate.visualization.html

Answer (score 0):

Google Colab is run in the Cloud. So, it can't open a new app window on your computer.

You may want to try [Local Runtime](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html)

Comment: I think colab visualization has been added to turicreate 6.0. (Sorry, I do not have a link yet.)